# SQL Server CHAR e VARCHAR

Tags: sql-server, char, varchar

Eu entendi bem a diferença entre `CHAR` e `VARCHAR`.

Se eu quero inserir em um campo `VARCHAR(10)` a palavra 'casa', essa palavra no banco irá ocupar 4 bytes.

Se eu quero inserir em um campo `CHAR(10)` a palavra 'casa', essa palavra no banco irá ocupar 10 bytes.

Está bem clara a diferença para mim, minha única dúvida é essa quantidade de bytes em relação ao `NULL`. Se eu deixar o campo `VARCHAR NULL` vai ficar **0 bytes**, no caso do `CHAR` vai ficar **10 bytes** travados mesmo estando `NULL`?

Answer (score 3):

Se o campo é fixo(`CHAR`) o tamanho de NULL tem o mesmo espaço que qualquer outro valor - o tamanho do campo.

Se o campo é de tamanho variável(`VARCHAR`) o valor NULL não ocupa espaço.

Em adição ao espaço requerido para armazenar um valor nulo, há também uma sobrecarga de ter uma coluna nula. Para cada linha um pouco é usado por coluna anulável para marcar se o valor para essa coluna é nulo ou não. Isso é verdadeiro se a coluna for comprimento fixo ou variável.